# Boost thread resources and mutexes

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I'm implementing a simple threaded application in which I have a server thread, and a gui thread. So, the thing goes a bit like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    appMain app(argc, argv);
    return app.exec();
}

appMain::appMain(int c, char **v) : argc(c), argv(v) {
    this->Configuration();
}

int appMain::exec() {
    appServer Server;

    try {
        ServerThread = boost::thread(Server);

        ServerThread.join();
    } catch (...) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`appMain::Configuration` method just picks up a configuration file and loads it into a `struct appConfig`. The thing is, I need this structure to be modifiable from any place it might be used, which means I've got to use a mutex so as to avoid memory corruption.
Hoping to avoid any possible pointer problems and thread argument passing (which seems kind of painful), I decided to use a global variables, which I declared in appConfig.h:

```
struct appConfig config;
boost::mutex configMutex;
```

Thus I added my `extern` declarations where I use them:

appMain.cpp

```
extern struct appConfig config;
extern boost::mutex configMutex;
```

appServer.cpp

```
extern struct appConfig config;
extern boost::mutex configMutex;

appServer::appServer() {
    return;
}

void appServer::operator()() {
    configMutex.lock();
    cout << "appServer thread." << endl;
    configMutex.unlock();
}

appServer::~appServer() {
    return;
}
```

It seems to me that there shouldn't be any kind of problem at compile time, yet I get this nice gift:

```
appServer.o: In function `~appServer':
/usr/include/boost/exception/detail/exception_ptr.hpp:74: multiple definition of `configMutex'
appMain.o:/home/eax/CCITP/src/appMain.cpp:163: first defined here
appServer.o: In function `appServer':
/usr/include/boost/exception/exception.hpp:200: multiple definition of `config'
appMain.o:/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_construct.h:94: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any insight on how I could solve this will be appreciated...

Julian.

Comment: Suggestion: Move the mutex inside the appConfig class/struct, and have it perform the locking on getter and setter methods. Forcing the client to remember to lock/unlock is going to be messy and error-prone.

Comment: That's a really good idea, I'd just have to use a class for the configuration. Will try after this is solved (not being able to solve this kind of gets me curious)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really a boost problem per se: you've declared a global variable in a header that's therefore defined in global scope in both compilation units, leading to multiple definitions.

Declaring it `extern` in the header, and defining it in exactly one .cpp file should work.